# Comparing cloud hosting technologies(Azure, EC2 or Google)

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-ec2

I'm going to start a simple SaaS application and am considering which cloud technology to go with(Azure, EC2 or Google).

Can someone who experience both (actual use)point the pros and cons(performence,costs,easy to develop,easy to maintain) of each technology and recommend his favorite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should one use the following: Amazon EC2, Google App Engine, Microsoft Azure and Salesforce.com?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518594/when-should-one-use-the-following-amazon-ec2-google-app-engine-microsoft-azure)

Answer (score 3):

Have you google'd this question?

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/windows-azure-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-google-app-engine
- [Windows Azure for web developers vs Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240724/windows-azure-for-web-developers-vs-amazon-ec2)
- http://programmerpayback.com/2009/02/04/scalable-windows-hosting-mosso-vs-ec2-vs-azure/
- http://news.techworld.com/data-centre/3228389/windows-azure-versus-amazon-ec2/

This has been asked quite frequently with some fantastic answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are big into Java(Grails, JRuby etc)+MySql+ tomcat development nothing beats AWS elastic beanstalk. It let's you create a "real" relational mysql database on their infrastructure. And they provide 1 year free usage tier but it does not include RDS

Azures is great for all things microsoft. Though one can use AWS for IIS and MSSQL based app I have not done the price comparison myself.

Google AE is great from price point of view but you have to leave some of your conventional development practices on a side, one of them being relational database. This was one of the biggest reason why I did not try GAE. There is no fun in writing Grails app without the powerful GORM.

Answer (score -3):

In current market other also provide cloud services like Microsoft Azure, Google. Then why Amazon? and what different service AWS provide than others. Amazon holds more than 36% stake in the cloud market. Also, top companies including Fortune 500 use Amazon Web Services. They all host their servers on AWS. The main reason behind is Amazon provide good service also its services are low cost comparatively others service, providers.

**Why we need to learn AWS?**

1) AWS is the leader and Fastest growing in the Cloud Computing market

2) It has more job opportunities than any other Cloud Provider

3) It has a more mature model of infrastructure, hence has a full stack of services, which complement each other

4) Companies are reserving a large share of their IT budget for upgrades and innovations in the cloud.

Here You will get a detailed description

https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2018/04/why-learn-amazon-web-services-aws-and.html